# Assuming monotonicity and concavity

Tags: assumptions

I have an expression that I would like to evaluate:

```
2 phi''[1 + a (-1 + u[10])] phi'[q]^3 > phi''[q] phi'[q] phi'[1 + a (-1 + u[10])]^2
```

Is there any way of telling Mathematica that the function `phi` is strictly increasing and convex?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "evaluate"? Have `a`, `u[10]`, and `q` been given definite real values or do you want to find combinations of them for which the inequality might be true for some `phi`?

Comment: Ideally the latter, but I'd be happy I got as far as Mathematica giving me back a True or False when I pin down all three of these things to particular values.